# What kind of rice can I use in a salt shaker to prevent clumping

Tags: rice

Will brown rice eliminate clumps in the salt shaker as well as white rice?  I know white rice works well in a salt shaker to eliminate clumps caused by humidity, but I only have brown rice on hand.  Will brown rice work as well as white rice?

Comment: Rice in shalt shakers is a urban myth. Modern table salts contain anti-caking agents; if the rice has any influence, it's due to mechanical shattering of (unlikely) clumps. Brown or white makes no difference.

Comment: I wouldn't use brown since it has a relative short shelf life, 6 months compared to years for white rice. Not that either will help a lot.

Comment: Instead of adding rice - consider getting a salt grinder and use rock salt instead. You can even buy disposable grinders with salt already in them.

Answer (score 3):

I do this at home, and it makes a significant difference.  I suspect that it is the mechanical action of the rice, but since adding a teaspoon of rice to each shaker, I don't have to get out the toothpick ever few weeks to clean the hole.

Brown rice includes the germ (embryo) of the grain, which contains some oil.  This oil goes rancid, which has an unpleasant smell.  In the quantities that you are using, and that the oil is still inside the rice, I don't think you would notice.

Note that it doesn't have to be rice.  a few beans, some barley, lentils, or wheat should work just as well.